# CentOS: Unable to start Postfix after upgrade to version 3

Tags: postfix, centos7, upgrade

We are running CentOS 7, and just upgraded Postfix to version 3. Postfix won't start after the upgrade. First, there is a compatibility issue in the log, but we resolved it as suggested (`postconf compatibility_level=2`).

A greater problem is

```
postfix: /usr/libexec/postfix/post-install: Error: /etc/postfix/postfix-files is not a file
```

Absolutely stuck there. We tried to set `chmod 777` on `/etc/postfix`, we tried to use `postfix-install`, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the solution. `/etc/postfix/postfix-files` was missing, so we just used:

```
touch /etc/postfix/postfix-files
```

...and the problem solved.

Comment: while it works, it's definitely not how it should be: I checked on another server of mine and the file is a list of all postfix files automatically generated. The header says `# This file controls the postfix-install script for installation of Postfix programs, configuration files and documentation, as well as the post-install script for setting permissions and for updating Postfix configuration files. See the respective manual pages within the script files.`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after updating postfix from http://repos.oostergo.net/7/postfix-3.2/

The file seems to be installed in `/usr/share/postfix/` though, so a better solution than simply creating an empty file is probably to copy it to the location where `post-install` expects to find it:

```
cp -a /usr/share/postfix/postfix-files /etc/postfix/
```

Answer (score 0):

Postfix looks for that postfix-files file in the directory specified by the [meta_directory](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#meta_directory) configuration option. Some packages seem to install that to `/usr/share/postfix`. My main.cf (and presumably yours) had it set to `/etc/postfix/` instead, and that seems to be the default that postfix uses in the absense of any configuration. (Packages that put it elsewhere put the right path in their default main.cf, but that of course doesn't help if you aren't using their default configuration and using your own file instead.) The solution is to set it in main.cf to where the installation package is actually putting it, such as

```
meta_directory = /usr/share/postfix
```